# How I can waiting some time in c# (windows service)

Tags: c#, service, wait

I created windows service on C#.
For now I have methods for scanning DB.
I need call this method two times per minute. Actually I don't know method for waiting in windows service. 
I tried Thread.Sleep... but nothing happened.
Please help me with this problem.

```
private int wait;
protected void Start()
{
    wait = 1000;
    while (true)
    {
        if (wait < 30000)
            wait += wait;

        //implement logic for waiting

        Video video = new Video();
        video.FindFileForConvert();
        if (video.Path != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("video != null. video path = {0}", video.Path);
            video.BeginConvertation();
            video.DeleteOriginFile();
            wait = 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Timer, and do your job on timer events.

Comment: what is the interval used in Thread.Sleep()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdh6857z.aspx)

```
public static int Main() {
   /* Adds the event and the event handler for the method that will 
      process the timer event to the timer. */
   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

   // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
   myTimer.Interval = 5000;
   myTimer.Start();

   // Runs the timer, and raises the event. 
   while(exitFlag == false) {
      // Processes all the events in the queue.
      Application.DoEvents();
   }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) for the same. Since `Thread.sleep` is not a good practice atleast in some cases.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between `System.Threading.Timer` and `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` ? I'm curious to see why one is better practice than the other.

Comment: @Nolonar  [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8928906/1064610) and this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I think that this code will help you resolve your problem. [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

```
DispatcherTimer dispathcerTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispathcerTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
dispathcerTimer.Tick += dispathcerTimer_Tick;
dispathcerTimer.Start();

void dispatcherTime_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
  //function, which needs to be invoked every two minutes.     
}
```

Comment: I think `DispatcherTimer` would be more appropriated for UI-related tasks.